# Listview and how to control items inside it with a button

Tags: android

I am trying to make a list and inside it I put a button.

This list consists of the button and two textviews.

I use this button to share the two textviews but when I click it shows me different data for different items on the list.

Here's the code:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page_custom_layout ,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.user = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.User_txt);
        holder.link = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lnk_txt);
        holder.time= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_txt);
        holder.desc= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link_desc_textview);
        holder.like= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_imageView);
        holder.share= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share_imageview);
        holder.like.setOnClickListener(this);
        //***shre item content
        view.setTag(holder);
        holder.like.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
        holder.share.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
        holder.link.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
        holder.desc.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
        holder.share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        lnkModelList.get(position).getLink_desc()+"\n"+
                                lnkModelList.get(possition).getLink()
                                +"\n"+"#LNKAPP");
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share LNK wite People"));
            }
        });

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.user.setText(lnkModelList.get(position).getUserName());
    holder.link.setText(lnkModelList.get(position).getLink());
    holder.time.setText(lnkModelList.get(position).getTime());
    holder.desc.setText(lnkModelList.get(position).getLink_desc());

    return view;
}
```

the lnkModel class-->

```
public class LnkModel {

       private String userName;
       private String link;
       private String time ;
       private String link_desc;

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getLink_desc() {
        return link_desc;
    }

    public void setLink_desc(String link_desc) {
        this.link_desc = link_desc;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    } 
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is going to be the use of OnClickListener. From what I see it looks like you need to be using OnItemSelected Instead. If that isn't your problem you may need to create a custom adapter that will implement the OnClickListener for the button. [This Answers how to do that nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076985/listview-row-buttons-how-do-i-create-a-custom-adapter-that-connects-a-view-oncl). One of these solutions should fix your problem

Comment: but i can not use `OnItemClickListener()` inside my adapter for the share button i

Comment: ok then you will need a custom adapter in which you can implement the OnClickListneners this explains the process very well [custom adapter for buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076985/listview-row-buttons-how-do-i-create-a-custom-adapter-that-connects-a-view-oncl)

Comment: in may adapter i am all ready implement OnClickListneners()

`public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LnkModel> implements OnClickListener  {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
`

Comment: Can you post your lnkModelList class so I can see how it is performing its actions? if it is giving wrong data, and you have a custom adapter then the problem is probably in how that class is executing its methods. Maybe how it interacts with your custom ListView.

Comment: if lnkModelList  is an implementation of your custom adapter then please post that class so we can see how it is implementing its methods

Comment: i have updated my code see the lnkModel class now 
thanks for helping

Comment: Well the answer was probably in front of us the whole time. This is probably it. 
change this 
lnkModelList.get(position).getLink_desc()+"\n"+
                                lnkModelList.get(possition).getLink()

to this 

lnkModelList.get(position).getLink_desc()+"\n"+
                                lnkModelList.get(position).getLink()

It appears to be just a typo in position.
Sorry about the late response I had to run out for a while

Comment: thanks alot, but the problem is not solved after changing possition to position

Comment: what about in your constructor. you have position declared as a final int that may be holding bad data. you might try initializing that as being accessible in the method.

Comment: public View getView( int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
this.position=position;

Comment: but if i remove final i notice that position access from inner class so it should be final 
and also if i implement OnClickListener and remove int the problem is exist 
 for example i have ten list item on my screen when i click on the button of every item give me the right position but  i scroll up and new ten item come again start to count from zero again

Comment: OK I understand but you are using position as a place holder not performing mutilating operations on the Int. Also I can't think of any reason a variable passed in should be final. even ones I didn't want to change because it prevents accessing them from inner tasks. When I see a final in a constructor like that its usually because I forgot something. Try this

Comment: public Class something Extends something{        
         //define variables used by most of the methods
         // values they will share or will be constant through out
         // Int position 
        // String value
          public something(int position, String value)
                    this.value=value;
                   this.position=position;